# NSThread not executing in sequence

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering how come my lines of codes does not seem to be executing in sequence. Below are snippets of my codes as follows.

```
- (void)myThreadMethod:(id)options
{
    NSInteger random = [self GetRandomNumber:12];

    NSLog(@"Random Number: %ld",(long)random);
    [self ChangeSquareColor:random:[UIColor redColor]];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];

    [self ChangeSquareColor:random:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    NSLog(@"Color changed");
}



-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)button.tag);
    //New thread
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myThreadMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)ChangeSquareColor:(NSInteger)Number
                        :(UIColor*)color
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:Number];
    button.backgroundColor = color;
}

-(NSInteger)GetRandomNumber:(NSInteger)Number
{
    return arc4random() % Number;
}
```

For some weird reason,     [self ChangeSquareColor:random:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];  seems to be called first followed by [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];

Comment: If you do use `detachNewThreadSelector`, make sure your selector's method has an `@autoreleasepool` block. Better, just use GCD.

Comment: You don't understand threads so why are you using them? This is terribly dangerous. You should _never_ sleep a thread, and you should avoid threads if at all possible. Nothing you are doing here requires threads anyway. To create a delay, make an NSTimer to call you back after the delay, or use `dispatch_after`.

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` is not thread-safe, and should not be called from a background thread. I would imagine that if you changed `-ChangeSquareColor::` to dispatch it's work back to the main thread, things might work a little better.

```
-(void)ChangeSquareColor:(NSInteger)Number
                        :(UIColor*)color
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:Number];
        button.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}
```

Also, indications on the Internet are that `arc4random` is not thread-safe either, so you should probably also be cautious about that.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Sorry, but i'm running new to objective-c. By dispatch does that mean running as another thread? Because i'm trying to run ChangeSquareColor method in another thread as I've other purposes for the main thread.

Comment: There's pretty clearly a lot that you're not yet aware of on the OS X/iOS platforms. You should probably go read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html and then this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ipmcc's observation regarding dispatching all UI updates to the main queue (which is critical), you probably shouldn't be using `detachNewThreadSelector` at all.

To do something in the background, you could use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // what to do in the background
});
```

To do something in the background, that updates the UI:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // what to do in the background

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // update UI here
    });
});
```

Thus, going back to your example:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)button.tag);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSInteger randomNumber = [self generateRandomNumber:12];

        NSLog(@"Random Number: %ld", (long)randomNumber);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self changeSquareNumber:randomNumber color:[UIColor redColor]];
        });

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self changeSquareNumber:randomNumber color:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        });
        NSLog(@"Color changed");
    });
}

- (void)changeSquareNumber:(NSInteger)squareNumber
                     color:(UIColor*)color
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:squareNumber];
    button.backgroundColor = color;
}

- (NSInteger)generateRandomNumber:(NSInteger)upperLimit
{
    return arc4random_uniform(upperLimit);
}
```

[Note, I changed your method names to conform to [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) (e.g. method names start with lowercase letters, start with a verb, avoid "get" and "set", make sure all parameters are named, etc.). I also used `arc4random_uniform` rather than `arc4random` with the `%` operator to avoid modulo bias.]

---

Or, even better, avoid blocking a thread (even if it's a global queue's worker thread) at all, and just trigger the initiation of the next step after a particular delay:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)button.tag);

    NSInteger randomNumber = [self generateRandomNumber:12];

    NSLog(@"Random Number: %ld",(long)randomNumber);
    [self changeSquareNumber:randomNumber color:[UIColor redColor]];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self changeSquareNumber:randomNumber color:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        NSLog(@"Color changed");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation. It worked like a charm! However, I tried modifying your codes to generate 4 random numbers into an nsmutablearray and to highlight and unhighlight the squares but to no avail.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose on the basis of the meager information provided. Are you seeing your log statements? If not, you might not have your `IBAction` hooked up properly. If you are seeing your log statements in the console, but you're not seeing the UI changes, then the question is whether `viewWithTag` is retrieving a non-`nil` reference. I'm sorry, but diagnosing this is going to require you to go through the execution, line-by-line and discovering precisely where it's going awry. Regarding the mutable array question, did you instantiate the mutable array before adding objects to it?

Comment: Yup, I did instantiate the mutable array. Below is a snippet of what i was trying to do 
- (void)myThreadMethod:(id)options
{
    NSInteger random = [self generateRandomNumber:12];
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    while(![self IsRandNoExist:random] &&
          counter < 4)
    {
        NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithLong:random];
        [self.randNumbers addObject:number];
        counter++;
        
        random = [self generateRandomNumber:12];
    }
for(NSNumber *no in self.randNumbers) {
[self ChangeSquareColor:[no integerValue]:[UIColor redColor]];

Comment: [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
        
        [self ChangeSquareColor:[no integerValue]:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    }

Comment: Set a breakpoint, run your code, step through that routine line by line. You gotta' learn how to use debugger to step through your code and observe how the variables change. (By the way, you say you instantiated the array, but then show me a code sample that doesn't instantiate `randNumbers`. Lol. I expected to see a line that says `self.randNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];` or the equivalent.)